# Simple online tool to draw circuit diagram / schematics?

Tags: discussion, support, formatting

I want to ask a quick question, and think a circuit diagram would make it a bit clearer, but I don't have any software for knocking one up, is there a recommended online tool I could use? It only needs a few simple symbols, it doesn't need to export (I could screen-shot it).

Then I can host the image on twitpic or similar, and include it in the body of my question.

Otherwise I'm going to draw it in paint!

PS - for this stack exchange site, it would be awesome to have a diagram tool built into the site, but if there is a free online tool, it might be worth reccomending it in the faq (just below where it says:)

> "We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic..."

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics/ is similar, but some of the answers are specifically for this site (belongs on meta), and some are not (belongs on main).

Answer (score 9):

http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

And you can export a link so that other people can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.circuitlab.com/ might be helpful.

Comment: This page opened a pay wall after a while and asked me to register. Seems this service is not for free anymore. Bad: It is not very clear when the user starts to draw and looses the work after an hour (or so) without registration.